# What is the probability of Event B happening is Event A MUST happen first.

Tags: probability

This was a question by brother asked me and I had no idea how to do it. I cannot remember the exact details of the question he asked me, so I've made up a question of my own that is similar.

Question 1.

A deck of cards has been split into their own suits, giving 4 piles of cards each in their own suit.

The probability of you picking at random the 'Hearts' pile is 1/4 (Event A).

The probability of you then picking at random the King of Hearts is 1/13 (Event B).

So, given that Event A must happen in order for Event B to happen, how do you calculate the overall probability of Event B taking place?

Answer (score 2):

You multiply the two probabilities!  So you first need to pick the hearts pile, which you have $1/4$ chance of doing.  Then you need to pick the King from that, which you have a $1/13$ chance of doing this.

But that means you have a $(1/4)(1/13) = 1/52$ chance of picking the King of Hearts.  So it turns out with this game you have the same chance of picking the King of Hearts as if you had just shuffled all of the cards together and then picked one of them at random.

Answer (score 0):

You could formalize it as:$$P\left(B\right)=P\left(B\mid A\right)P\left(A\right)+P\left(B\mid A^{c}\right)P\left(A^{c}\right)=\frac{1}{13}.\frac{1}{4}+0.\frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{52}$$

As said allready in the answer of user46944 it comes to the same as just picking out a card out of the whole deck. You can only pick out the King of hearts of you 'first' pick out for the 'mixed up' pile of hearts.